# Application send-keys highlighted in bold below does not work after shell screenshot code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long)
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd 
As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, 
ByVal _
bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Declare PtrSafe Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Global Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
'Declare Virtual Key Codes
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12
Public Const VK_TAB = &H9
Public Const VK_ENTER = &HD


Sub Automate_FAZAL_Enter_Data()

'Variables add/modify as required
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim HWNDSrc As Long
Dim LastRow, i, j As Integer
Dim P As Range
Dim S As Range
Dim T As String
Dim Default


Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


Set sht_ELMTS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Elements")

'Loop start

For j = 3 To LastRow


'Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'
Set P = sht.Cells(j, 8)
Set N = sht.Cells(j, 9)
Set S = sht.Cells(j, 32)

MsgBox "Loop Start for " & N
'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the 
background
IE.Visible = True

'Define URL

URL = "http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/javascript-alert-box-demo.html"

apiShowWindow IE.hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
'Navigate to URL
IE.Navigate URL

' Statusbar tells website is loading
Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

' Wait while IE loading...

Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

'Webpage Loaded
Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"


HWNDSrc = IE.hWnd

SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

'some data will be entered

'=====================================================
'Section 1 second snapshot
Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)


  Set WSH_OBJ = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WSH_OBJ.Run "mspaint"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  WSH_OBJ.AppActivate "untitled - Paint"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  'Application.SendKeys ("%{TAB}")
  WSH_OBJ.SendKeys "^v"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))
  WSH_OBJ.SendKeys "^s"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))
  WSH_OBJ.SendKeys "C:\Sayantan\Enrollment-" & P & "-" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Now(), "/", "-"), " ", ""), ":", "") & "_" & N & "_Section1_BOTTOM_" & ".jpg"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  WSH_OBJ.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
  WSH_OBJ.SendKeys "%f"

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
  WSH_OBJ.SendKeys "x"

  Set WSH_OBJ = Nothing
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))


 '===============================================================


  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
  Dim e
  Set e = IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("btn btn-default btn-lg")(0)


  ***e.Click 'Confirmation box will appear*** THIS button activates 
  confimation box and user has to select ok or cancel
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

  ***Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'i am trying to select ok via sendkeys 
  but this does not work***


        IE.Quit

 MsgBox "End"

Next j

'=================================================================
'Unload IE
Set IE = Nothing


End Sub
```

I am not sure how to click on ok without compromising existing code
this issue occurs only after the MS paint(Screenshot) code otherwise i am able to send keys to IE
Application send-keys highlighted in bold below does not work after shell screenshot code

Application send-keys highlighted in bold below does not work after shell screenshot code

Answer (score 0):

If it is a normal IE popup and not a Java Web Applet or other Add-on popup you can use the following code:

These are API Calls to find a popup in IE, I have them on a separate Module.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hWND As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5&
```

The following portion looks for a popup with the title "Message from webpage", you can change it if the popup has a different title. If it finds it, it will look for the OK Button, if it finds that, it will send the Click to it. (You can replace "OK" for "Cancel" to find and press Cancel instead).

You will replace the SendKeys ENTER with the code below.

```
hWND = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Message from webpage")
If hWND <> 0 Then childHWND = FindWindowEx(hWND, ByVal 0&, "Button", "OK")
If childHWND <> 0 Then SendMessage childHWND, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
```

Comment: Needs to define variables: ` hWND` and `childHWND`

Comment: I have the API Calls on a different module to avoid the Option Explicit from forcing me to define them.

Comment: You meant they are defined in another module as Public, if so then you still need to include them in your answer same as you included `Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5&`.